# pass class object of one class via another class

Tags: java

My classes are getting little complex at the moment. What I want to do is that I have class lets say classA which has few functions and I have two other classB and junitclassC.

I don't understand how should I pass classA object to  classB via junitclassC class.

So far what I have done is

```
Class junitclassC{
    public void passObject(){
        classB b;
    } 
}
```

I want use this passObject method which has classB object from class junitclassC to another class A.

any idea how can I pass object of classB through this method  passObject() ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass classA object o classB via junitclassC class"? This is really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate a new object by calling ClassA constructor and then pass it as parameter to the constructor of ClassB.